# Приложение крашится из-за background service

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, background-task

Доброго времени суток, суть проблемы:

Приложение имеет `Service`, который проверяет наличие новых заказов на сервере.

Если приложение свернуть, `Service` исправно выдаёт уведомления в шторку, но при завершении приложения, вместо уведомлений каждую минуту, выскакивает отчёт о краше этого приложения.

Не могу понять в чём проблема.

Листинг кода прилагаю:

MyDataReceiver:

```
public class MyDataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    }
}
```

UpdateService:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

    private Context context;
    private Timer timer;
    private UpdateTask timerTask;

    //public UpdateService(Context _context) {context = _context;}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timerTask = new UpdateTask(getApplicationContext());

            timer.schedule(timerTask, 30000, 60000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

UpdateTask:

```
public class UpdateTask extends TimerTask {

    private Context context;
    public UpdateTask(Context _context) {context = _context;}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (WorkSQLite.ReadOrders(context).size() == 0)
            new OrdersFromDB.CheckNewOrders(context).execute(context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString());
    }
}
```

NotificationService:

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {
    NotificationManager nm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sendNotif();
    }

    public NotificationService() {
        super(NotificationService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sendNotif();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    void sendNotif() {
        Notification myNotification;

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemsListActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setTicker("Hey. New Orders!");
        builder.setContentTitle("Flower Deliver Car");
        builder.setContentText("You have a new orders");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        //builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
        //builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);

        myNotification = builder.getNotification();
        //myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
        //startForeground(1, myNotification);
        nm.notify(1, myNotification);
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

CheckNewOrders:

```
public static class CheckNewOrders extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private Context context;

        public CheckNewOrders(Context _context) {
            this.context = _context;
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String track = "";
            try {track += "track=" + FileSys.readFile(urls[0]);}
            catch (Exception ex) {SysEx.ExMessage(ex);}

            String url_all_products = "http://93.170.141.12:8080/api/app/checkneworders?" + track + "&" + "key=" + KEY + "&" + "cash=" + CashFunc.getCash(KEY);

            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url_all_products);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    int success = jsonObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) return true;

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean flag) {
            //if (flag) super.onPostExecute(flag);
            //else super.onPostExecute(flag);
            if (flag) context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
        }
    }
```

StackTrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
                                                                                  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                      at com.example.zaki.deliverflowerscar.Service.UpdateTask.run(UpdateTask.java:22)
                                                                                      at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:607)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:190)
                                                                                      at com.example.zaki.deliverflowerscar.Service.UpdateTask.run(UpdateTask.java:22) 
                                                                                      at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: Я завершаю приложение, и только после Service начинает крашить прилагу. Ввиду завершения я не могу забрать стектрейс

Comment: Не вижу проблемы, просто снимите фильтр (чтобы в logcat отображались все сообщения) и самостоятельно там поищите стек-трейс Вашего приложения.

Comment: @post_zeew, понял, исправился